# How can I add a number to a given element of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have `a=[1,2,3]` and I want to add `1` to element `a[2]` to get the output  `[1,2,4]`, how would I do that?

I assume I would use a for loop but not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

Lists in python are mutable.

What's wrong with:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a[2] = a[2] + 1
a
[1,2,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a[2] += 1
>>> a
[1, 2, 4]
```

Or, if you want to add `1` to the last element of an array regardless of its size:

```
>>> a[-1] += 1
>>> a
[1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
a[:2]+[a[2]+1]
```

where you can replace 2 with position you want to add to, or simply

```
a[2] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop iterates through all the elements in the list. If you want to address a particular element in the list you have to call it individually.

```
a = [1,2,3]
a[2] +=1
print(a)
```